# Can't click my button inside ng-repeat using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat repeating some data from my table and on each card there's a button you can press, I want this button to just make an alert when you press it and this is my current code:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in ids">
        <div class="row">
              <!--<div class="col s12 m6">-->
              <center>
        <div class="flipcard">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                  <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <p>{{data.amount}} coin wager with {{data.posted_nickname}}
                    <a id="joinflip" class="right waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">games</i>Play</a>                  </div>
                         </div>
                         </div>
                         </center>

            </div>

      </div>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
     $("#joinflip").click(
         function () {
             alert("Alert Message OnClick");
         }            
     );
 });
```

The button works outside of the ng-repeat loop but when within ng-repeat it never triggers the onclick, thanks for any help

Comment: do try out this `app = angular.module('two_way', []);
app.controller('two_way_control', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    load_pictures();
    $interval(function() {
        load_pictures();
    }, 300);

    function load_pictures() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/loadcoinflips').success(function(data) {
            $scope.ids = data;
        });
    };
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        alert('Called')
    }
});`

Comment: Strongly suggest reading: [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/1175966)

Comment: Good answer but you should've noted this was for ngClick, thanks for the repsonse though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because ng-repeat elements are created after document fired 'ready' event. You should use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead.

Comment: Sorted it! Did some reading up on ngClick and was exactly what I needed thanks.

Comment: Sorry very new to SO, will try and do it now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the DOM is not ready yet.
you need to use event delegation (you need to use a class instead of an ID because they will repeat)

```
$(document).on("click", ".joinflip", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

Hope it help :D

Comment: Though  I didn't downvoted your answer..but could you explain, how can this would work with angular?

Comment: Can't have duplicate ID's in a  page. This won't work. And how do you plan to integrate this with angular scope

Comment: @charlietfl are you sure, i didn't see that is an loop, i just updated the answer.

Comment: `ng-repeat` is most certainly a loop. Making the suggestion you are making is just not  a good practice in an angular app

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however this doesn't work and ngClick is needed, I have now fixed it, thanks.